# Pytorch Tensor help in LongTensor

Tags: pytorch, tensor

```
a=[1,2,3];
context_var = autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor(a))
```

This is giving an error

```
RuntimeError: tried to construct a tensor from a int sequence, but found an item of type numpy.int32 at index
```

I am not able to figure out how to get over this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine in the recent version of pytorch. But for older versions, you can convert the `numpy` array to list using `.tolist()` method as follows to get rid of the error.

```
a=[1,2,3];
context_var = autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor(a.tolist()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
a=[1,2,3]
print(torch.autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor(a)))
b = np.array(a)
print(torch.autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor(b)))
```

outputs:

```
Variable containing:
 1
 2
 3
[torch.LongTensor of size 3]

Variable containing:
 1
 2
 3
[torch.LongTensor of size 3]
```

I'm using Python 3.6.2, torch 0.2.0.post3, and numpy 1.13.3.